# Get attributes of the target div in ngDraggable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two container div which has many items in it. I'm using `ngDraggable` for dragging these items . I need to get the attributes of the container div into with the item is dropped.When I check, what I'm getting is the attributes of the target `item` and not the `container` div. How can I get the attributes of the outer div ?

Edit

```
<div id="containerdiv">
    <div id="item" ng-repeat="(qKey, qn) in list"  ng-drop="true" ng-drop-success="onDropComplete($index, $data,$event)">
</div>
```

ondrop function

```
$scope.onDropComplete = function (index, obj, evt) {
   console.log(index) // returns the dragged items attributes
});
```

Comment: Please add your code here or create jsfiddle

Comment: Please add kind of code...  anyway.. did you tried parentnode? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentnode.asp

Comment: You can add a controller to the outer container div.Move the onDropComplete function to that controller. And you will have reference to the element (container div)

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have can you please share it because I am also struggling with exactly the same issue. I can always get id of div from which it is dropped and never an Id of div where it is dropped...

Comment: Nidhin, erro505, was this issue resolved for you ? If yes then can you please share some pointer as how. I am facing same issue. I am getting dropped object attributes instead of actual target container where object is being dropped.

Answer (score 0):

It is a 3 year old post and probably unresolved for the one who logged this issue in stack-overflow.  I tried to contact them to check if they have resolved but no response came.

I was facing similar issue and I have prepared a workable solution (at-least working for me). If anyone facing similar issue while using ngdraggable then please check the solution mentioned by me in link below.

> [When used in table cell(td), ngDraggable not giving target container attributes where an item is being dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033630/when-used-in-table-celltd-ngdraggable-not-giving-target-container-attributes)